# Jest Mocking or Spying on React.useContext errors TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I've seen this error elsewhere but it's not the same use case.

Libraries in play:

```json
    "react": "~16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "~3.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "~10.4.7",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "~7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "~7.29.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "~5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "~12.6.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "~24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "~24.9.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "~7.0.4",
```

Running Jest with Testing Library, I am getting this error:

```sh
  ● NoResultsPanel › renders and matches screenshot

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

      22 | export const themeRender = (children) => ({
      23 |   theme: defaultTheme,
    > 24 |   root: rtlRender(<ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>)
         |         ^
      25 | });
      26 |
      27 | export const brandWrapper = (children) => ({

      at phash (node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:683:13)
      at ComponentStyle.generateAndInjectStyles (node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1271:25)
      at useInjectedStyle (node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1497:120)
      at useStyledComponentImpl (node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1525:28)
      at forwardRef (node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1592:12)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
      at updateForwardRef (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16816:20)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18645:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21188:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24373:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24758:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21903:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:100:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at rtlRender (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:96:26)
      at themeRender (src/utils/tests/helpers.js:24:9)
      at Object.it (src/components/NoResults/NoResultsPanel.test.js:39:37)
```

and I've tried spying and mocking on `useContext`:

```js
// spy approach
const useContextSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useContext');
useContextSpy.mockReturnValue({
  PAGE_TITLES: { PEOPLE: () => '', RESULTS: () => '', KNOWLEDGE: () => 'Materials', CASES: () => '', CASES_LEGACY: () => '', LAB: () => '' }
});

// mock approach
jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useContext: () => ({ PAGE_TITLES: { PEOPLE: () => '', RESULTS: () => '', KNOWLEDGE: () => 'Materials', CASES: () => '', CASES_LEGACY: () => '', LAB: () => '' } })
}));
```

Both render the same error.

The `themeRender` mentioned in the error is a little helper for wrapping our components in our Styled Components theme.

```js
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
...
export const themeRender = (children) => ({
  theme: defaultTheme,
  root: rtlRender(<ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>)
});
```

If I remove my mock/spy on React, the error goes away, but then the context I'm trying to read from doesn't load, and as a result, my tests fail. Everything works great elsewhere, it's only an issue where `useContext` is being used as I can't get anything from it.

Comment: That's not a good thing to be doing anyway - you shouldn't mock what you don't own. Let `useContext` do its thing and render your components in a provider created for the tests, as shown on e.g. https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context/ or https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing.

Comment: Good call out. We're porting from Enzyme to Testing Library, so have some bad habits in here. Thanks!!